# why $(document).ready() run after window.onload?

Tags: jquery

in this thread its answered the window.onload is the most late when compared to jquery.ready

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698214/15185328

Also in this thread its stated the vanilla JS version of jquery ready is DOMContentLoaded (which is run much earlier than window.onload):

[$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

But when I tested it. jquery.ready is the most late compared with other event. Why is it?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready (jquery)");
});

jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
  console.log("onload (jquery)");
});

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
  console.log("onload (js)");
});

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log("DOMContentLoaded (js)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jvdw0kh8/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery [internally](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js) has a variable named `readyList`, which is a Deferred object that resolves when DOMContentLoaded fires. All calls to `.ready` go through that.

Once DOMContentLoaded fires, the deferred resolves, and all handlers connected to it fire. But, like Promises, handlers connected to the Deferred don't fire immediately - it takes place a bit of time later (after the equivalent of an immediate `setTimeout`).

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready (jquery)");
});  


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    console.log("DOMContentLoaded (js)");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('DOMContentLoaded microtask');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: So its wrong to say function inside jquery.ready run before window.onload? Can you recommend me on what event should i hook into to guarantee the most late without settimeout? native jquery/js event preferred

Comment: @gidiwe2427 what's your use-case? If you need access to elements, then either jQuery's _ready_ or `DOMContentLoaded` should be fine. If you need to wait for other assets to load, what are they?

Comment: If you have multiple scripts with depend on a particular execution order, and all use `.ready`, the best approach by far would be to refactor them so that you only have a single entry point, with a single `.ready`, inside which you can order other function calls as desired.